# How to use function a * x ^ m to approximate function with polyfit() or something similar in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of data and I need to compare some approximation functions.

I used `polyfit()` for logarithmic and exponential fitting, but how can I use it for function `a * x ^ m`?
It is a code for logarithmic regression:

```py
x = numpy.array([1, 7, 20, 50, 79])
y = numpy.array([10, 19, 30, 35, 51])
numpy.polyfit(numpy.log(x), y, 1)
array([ 8.46295607,  6.61867463])
#y ≈ 8.46 log(x) + 6.62
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want `y=ax^m` using linear fit, then take the logarithm of the equation `ln(y) = ln(a)+m*ln(x)`. Following your example, this should be `numpy.polyfit(numpy.log(x), numpy.log(y), 1)` giving `[ m, log(a) ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to calculate the value of each power of the independent variable, and then do matrix multiplication with the coefficient:

```
>>> deg = 1
>>> x = np.array([1, 7, 20, 50, 79])
>>> y = np.array([10, 19, 30, 35, 51])
>>> log_x = np.log(x)
>>> p = np.polyfit(log_x, y, deg)
>>> p @ np.vstack([log_x ** i for i in range(deg, -1, -1)])
array([ 6.61867463, 23.08682675, 31.97142527, 39.72595348, 43.59711987])
```

A simpler approach is to use `np.polyval`, it is calculated through a loop:

```
>>> np.polyval(p, log_x)
array([ 6.61867463, 23.08682675, 31.97142527, 39.72595348, 43.59711987])
```

However, NumPy advocates the use of `np.polynomial.Polynomial` in the new code:

```
>>> p = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(log_x, y, deg)
>>> p(log_x)
array([ 6.61867463, 23.08682675, 31.97142527, 39.72595348, 43.59711987])
```